# Creating Alias in Bash Profile for Python 3

Tags: python, bash

So I have a bunch of versions of Python installed and want access to Python 3.3 simply by entering `python` into terminal. I've read other posts but, for whatever reason, on my machine, it opens Python 2.7 when I enter `python` even though I've changed the alias in my bash profile.

For reference, my bash profile has the line:

```
alias python='python3'
```

Comment: Are you source’ing your profile after adding that line?

Comment: You need to either restart your terminal after the changes, or do `. ~/.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your Python 3 binary in `/bin/` is actually called `python3`, you also have to either reload your profile or exit the terminal in order for the new profile to be loaded